# spark-shell scala to map the exchange rate value in dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe df

```
+-----+--------+----------+-----+
|count|currency|      date|value|
+-----+--------+----------+-----+
|    3|     GBP|2021-01-14|    4|
|  102|     USD|2021-01-14|    3|
|  234|     EUR|2021-01-14|    5|
|   28|     GBP|2021-01-16|    5|
|   48|     USD|2021-01-16|    7|
|   68|     EUR|2021-01-15|    6|
|   20|     GBP|2021-01-15|    1|
|   33|     EUR|2021-01-17|    2|
|  106|     GBP|2021-01-17|   10|
+-----+--------+----------+-----+
```

I have a separate dataframe for USD exchange_rate

```
val exchange_rate = spark.read.format("csv").load("/Users/khan/data/exchange_rate.csv")
exchange_rate.show()

INSERTTIME  EXCAHNGERATE    CURRENCY
2021-01-14  0.731422        GBP
2021-01-14  0.784125        EUR
2021-01-15  0.701922        GBP
2021-01-15  0.731422        EUR
2021-01-16  0.851422        GBP
2021-01-16  0.721128        EUR
2021-01-17  0.771621        GBP
2021-01-17  0.751426        EUR
```

I want to convert the GBP and EUR currency to USD in `df` by looking in the exchange_rate dataframe corresponding to the date

**My Idea**

```
import com.currency_converter.CurrencyConverter from http://xavierguihot.com/currency_converter/#com.currency_converter.CurrencyConverter$
```

is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: Why not simply join the df with `exchange_rate` df and calculate column `value * EXCAHNGERATE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery (a fancy way of doing joins):

```scala
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df1")
exchange_rate.createOrReplaceTempView("df2")

val result = spark.sql("""
select count, 'USD' as currency, date, value,
    value * coalesce(
        (select min(df2.EXCAHNGERATE)
         from df2
         where df1.date = df2.INSERTTIME and df1.currency = df2.CURRENCY),
        1  -- use 1 as exchange rate if no exchange rate found
    ) as converted
from df1
""")

result.show
+-----+--------+----------+-----+---------+
|count|currency|      date|value|converted|
+-----+--------+----------+-----+---------+
|    3|     USD|2021-01-14|    4| 2.925688|
|  102|     USD|2021-01-14|    3|      3.0|
|  234|     USD|2021-01-14|    5| 3.920625|
|   28|     USD|2021-01-16|    5|  4.25711|
|   48|     USD|2021-01-16|    7|      7.0|
|   68|     USD|2021-01-15|    6| 4.388532|
|   20|     USD|2021-01-15|    1| 0.701922|
|   33|     USD|2021-01-17|    2| 1.502852|
|  106|     USD|2021-01-17|   10|  7.71621|
+-----+--------+----------+-----+---------+
```

Comment: The currency name should also be changed e.g from GBP to USD in 1st line

Answer (score 1):

You can join both `DataFrames` and operate by row

```
val dfJoin = df1.join(df2, df1.col("date") === df2.col("INSERTTIME") &&
  df1.col("currency") === df2.col("CURRENCY"),"left")#currecy should be changed to currency

dfJoin.withColumn("USD", col("value") * col("EXCAHNGERATE")).show()
```

Comment: Error in 2nd line, <console>:27: error: not found: value join
       join.withColmn("USD", col("value") * col("EXCAHNGERATE"))

Comment: sorry, join.withColumn is dfJoin, can you try again?

Comment: Error, <console>:29: error: value withColmn is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
       dfJoin.withColmn("USD", col("value") * col("EXCAHNGERATE")).show()

Comment: Edited, try again